# move document library with custom fields

Tags: sharepoint

I want to move lots of document libraries between different sharepoint sites(not in even same domain). I use "Windows Explorer Mode" for move document libraries but i can not move the custom columns which are added on libraries. My moved ones just include file.

By the way, i have following restrictions.

--I can not RDP to servers which are sharepoint servers are installed on.
--I am not site collection administrator on both site
--I can not reach List Templates menu on the Site Settings menu

So is there a way to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SharePoint serves are in different farms, and that your Document Libraries are contained within Publishing Sites, could you consider asking the Farm administrators to export / import the sites between the farms?

Comment: :) i wish i have a change. But there is realy strict policies about the access.(My target site's farm is managed by global team, i am member of local team, also outsource)